# jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()

Tags: jquery, positioning

What is the difference between `position()` and `offset()`? I tried to do the following in a click event:

```
console.info($(this).position(), $(this).offset());
```

And they seem to return exactly the same... (The clicked element is within a table cell in a table)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Whether they're the same depends on context.

- `position` returns a `{left: x, top: y}` object *relative to the offset parent*
- `offset` returns a `{left: x, top: y}` object *relative to the document*.

Obviously, if the document is the offset parent, which is often the case, these will be identical. The [offset parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) is "the closest positioned containing element."

For example, with this document:

```
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 200; left: 200;">
     <div id="sub"></div>
 </div>
```

Then the `$('#sub').offset()`  will be `{left: 200, top: 200}`, but its `.position()` will be `{left: 0, top: 0}`.

Comment: So the offset parent is the first parent with position set to absolute? or?

Comment: @Svish: whoa, did I really miss the code indent? thaks for the edit. yes, the offset parent is the closest *positioned* parent. that is, an element with position set to absolute, relative or fixed (but not static). this is not a jQuery or even a javascript thing, you have the same behavior in css: if you were to give `sub` absolute positioning to 0:0, then it will be in the top left corner of the offset parent.

Comment: FYI, `.position` got updated in 1.12.0 => https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1708

Comment: Isn't opposite to the instinctive point of view? This is so arbitrary! For me an absolute "point" is a position. A relative "point" is an offset.

Answer (score 30):

> The **.offset()** method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element **relative to the document**. Contrast this with **.position()**, which retrieves the **current position relative to the offset parent**. When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop), .offset() is the more useful.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: As asked above, what is considered the offset parent? It seems that calling position() on the first div inside another div does not always return 0,0 - even when there is no other styling or positioning going on.

Comment: jquery.offsetParent(): http://api.jquery.com/offsetparent/ "Get the closest ancestor element that is positioned."

Answer (score -7):

Both functions return a plain object with two properties: width & height.

> offset() refers to the position relative to the document.
>
> position() refers to the position relative to its parent element

BUT when the object's css position is "absolute" both functions will return width=0 & height=0

Comment: Correction: offset and position returns a object with left and top properties, not width and height.