# Why i am getting same value in offset and position in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have placed a span inside of the paragraph tag, now the position top should show as 0 and the offset should show some other value (need to calculate from document), but i am getting the same value in both...

i am wrong?

this is my code:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<p>paragraph<span>span</span>paragraph</p>
```

Jquery:

```
$('span').click(function(){
console.log($(this).position().top,$(this).offset().top)
})

CSS:

p{
  color:green;
}

span{
  color:red;
}

div{
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BhsrS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the `docs`

The `.position()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element `relative to the offset parent`.

Contrast this with `.offset()`, which `retrieves the current position relative to the document`.

When positioning a new element near another one and within the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful.

If we talk about your scenario then :

> Currrently both `.position()` and `.offset()` have same parent and they will get the offset position of the document.

Now if you add one more attribute in the css class of `<p>` `position:relative;` you can find the difference then.

In short:

`.offset().top` will get the top from the document.

`.position().top` will get the top from the relative parent.(if parent is relatively set)

you can find the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/BhsrS/1/

checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BhsrS/1/

Answer (score 4):

Set the `position` property of the `p` tag to `relative`:

```
p {
  color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPdxB/

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)

Position referes to the position relative to the **offset parent** which is actually the document in your example, because the p is not a positioned element, but rather inline. That is why you are getting the same values back.

if you make your p element have absolute or relative positioning, the position of the span will now be relative to the P element as you originally expected, and therefore a different value from offset.