# Scrolling a <div> to Specific Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a split page with a menu on the left, and the main content on the right. When I click on a menu item, I want to scroll the main content to that item.

I found JavaScript `scrollTo()`, which takes offset arguments.

Is there any way to determine the offset of a particular `<p>` or other element within a `<div>`? Or perhaps there is another way to scroll to an element without knowing its offset?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies. Looks like everyone gave similar answers. However, I ran into a problems with this. It seems that `offset().top` (or `position().top`) return different values depending on the current scroll position.

My jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gBTW9/4/embedded/result/

If I scroll to the top and selection Section 4, it works as expected. But once I've scrolled, it stops working correctly. Can anyone see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are jquery methods [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) stat can help there.

Also there is good [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin which accepts elements and much more.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a problem with `offset().top` and `position().top`. Could you review the edit to my question?

Comment: Fixed your script code, you have to add current scroll position here http://jsfiddle.net/gBTW9/7/

Comment: Wow, yes. I didn't think those would work with the split layout I had but I see they do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the vertical offset of an element using `$('p').offset().top`. You can combine this with `scrollTop()` using this:

```
$('div').scrollTop($('p').offset().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use position() rather than offset(). If you know the id of that

you can easily find the position of that paragraph tag

[jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a problem with `position().top`. Could you review the edit to my question?

Answer (score 1):

If i didn't misunderstood you just need an animated scrolling to a particular element, something similar on what I did on [my portfolio](http://luigimannoni.com).

Assuming that the menu on the left is fixed, then just scroll the page to the element you want to scroll to:

```
$("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: $('#element').offset().top 
});
```

If you need to move a particular element over another element then:

```
$("#element1").animate({
   top: $('#element2').offset().top 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a problem with `offset().top`. Could you review the edit to my question?

Comment: The guilty here is `#main-content { position: fixed; }` and it messes up the offset calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Why try it the hard way, when you can use a HTML native attribute??

call me old school, but i like to keep it simple.

within your menu:

use:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#Paragraph1">Paragraph 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```
<ul>
    <li>Paragraph 1</li>
</ul>
```

this will make your section jump to the # (id) that equals Paragraph1

Comment: Yes, antejan also suggested this.