# How to make an element visible after went to its position

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

I want to make an object visible when user goes to its location in an HTML document

When user scrolled to bottom (Or typed 'pagename.html#bottom' on URL bar) bottom `<div>` should be visible. How to write a code for this using html, css and javascript?

Here is an example page

```html
<div id="top">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div id="bottom" style="visibility:hidden">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you accept coffee too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518148/how-to-show-data-only-when-in-viewport

Comment: If you can use jQuery, i will post an answer that might help you.

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar  I don't know cofee bro! :lol

Comment: @mplungjan It's Jquery bro! I can't understand.

Comment: @subodhkalika I don't know Jquery bro.So, If you give a full code i accept it.

Comment: @ShonMax SO is not a free code-writing site. The answers/comments already told you what you need to know, it is on you to learn it.

Comment: We are not your "Bro"s - I did not hammerclose since you had not tagged jQuery

Comment: @ShonMax I have posted an answer which is working for me. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: OK!  Sorry! I said 'bro' as you are my friends(brothers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this using [`window.location.hash`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikkM6svc3YAhXFOY8KHa22BjgQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_loc_hash.asp&usg=AOvVaw3Gv16wViPtnwt3S7GSCo6M)

**Explanation**

1. `window.location.hash` is pick the data of the hash value from the url
   `html#bottom`.its just get `#bottom`.
2. Then target the element with id name `document.querySelector('#bottom')`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("'" + window.location.hash + "'").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the code bro. Can you make it complete with codes i entered at question for understand it easy?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your body should be scrollable.

You can acheive it by setting the overflow property

```
  body {
        overflow: auto;
  }
```

Now to check if the element is visible in the viewport or not.

You have to use the scroll event.
The scroll event fires when you scroll on the body.

```
    $('body').scroll(function(event) {
            if($('#bottom').offset().top < window.innerHeight) {
                  $('#bottom').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
    });
```

Javascript:

```
   window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        if(document.getElementById('bottom').offsetTop < window.innerHeight) {
              document.getElementById(bottom).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with jquery;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#bottom").hide();
            console.log( "ready!" );
        });     
        document.onscroll = function() {
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight)
        {
            console.log("scrolled");
            alert("scrolled to bottom");
            $("#bottom").show();
        }

    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </P>
        </div>
        <div >
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. I am the last statement before reaching bottom.
            </P>
        </div>



        <div id="bottom">
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. i am in the bottom.
            </P>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```