# displaying table row that is hidden in scrollbar

Tags: jquery, row, html-table, hidden

Following is my basic html code of a table in my project.

```
<table>
    <tr id='someId'>
        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this table I have multiple rows nearly 100's of them and the height of the div that contains this table is small so there is a scrollbar to this div.

Some of the checkbox is selected by default and is done in jquery and works fine.

The problem is I want to display the last check box that is checked in that scrollbar as if it is at the bottom of the table then it gets hidden in that scrollbar.
hence i want to scroll down where the last check box is checked so that it gets displayed directly in jquery.

please help ..

Comment: Do you have any jquery script you have started with?

Comment: no actually i dont where to start from ..

Comment: a good start is to search for method `scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a draft version of how to write it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollTo = $('input:checked').last().offset().top;
    $('#idOfDivToScroll').scrollTop(scrollTo);
});
```

Some good reading related to the topic:

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowpos = $('#table input:checked').last().position();
    $('#container').scrollTop(rowpos.top);
});
```

Should focus on the last element of the table

**EDIT:**
Check out this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2968/)

Comment: Check out the fiddle , now it will focus on the last checked input

Comment: position() does only work when the page is scrolled to the top.

Comment: You can also use offset() in place of position(). Above code will work

Comment: @Streamside  check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset  It is good to use offset, but postion will also work.