# Getting position of draggable element relative to (inside of) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, parent-child, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some draggable text and I would like to get it's coordinates within an element.

The text is made draggable through this code:

```
$("span.output").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {}
});
```

I also have this piece of code which is supposed to make the draggable text the child of the element the draggable text is in:

```
$('.container').on('drop', function(event, ui){
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
});
```

When I try `$('#text1').position();` in console when the draggable text is within in the container, I get these coordinates:

```
Object {top: 57.11805772781372, left: 779.4444580078125}
```

Unfortunately, these are wrong.  Is what I am trying to do even possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Try using `offset()` and check out this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset

Comment: `offset()` does not seem to work either.  According to the article you linked, wouldn't I want to be using `position()` anyways?

Comment: What is #text1? Is that an element inside the draggable?

Comment: #text1 is a draggable span.  It is the draggable element that I put inside the stationary element.  Essentially, I want the coordiantes of  #text1 within the container, as if the container was the entire webpage...I figured creating a parent-child relationship between the two would allow me to do that.

Comment: If you're looking for a relative position, you're going to have to determine the position of the parent element and then subtract the resulting position of the dropped element.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem.

You are using

```
$('#text1').position();
```

It will give the postion relative to the container.

If you want the position relative to the document use this.

```
$('#text1').offset();
```

It has have `$('#text1').offset().left` and `$('text1').offset().right`

It might help..

Comment: May be `offset()` just have two properties `top` and `left` ? It should be `$('#text1').offset().top` and `$('#text1').offset().left` ?