# Do jquery .position().top and javascript .offsetTop do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, parent-child, offset

I am clear on the difference between `.offset()` and `.position()` in jquery (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)), however I am confused about how these map to javascript functions. Based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop) article it seems like `.offsetTop` in javascript does the same thing as `.position().top` in jquery. Is that true? If so, how do you get the behavior of `.offset()` in javascript? If not, how do you get the behavior of `.position()`?

Thanks!

Comment: You might find it interesting http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.position

Comment: For a quick reference if anyone wants the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f7e60dc83d81cbf892de9dab39642dd67c49bd23/src/offset.js), starting at line 109

Comment: Thanks @dfsq and @LcLk!
Based on this source code, it looks like the equivalent of `.position().top` would be `elem.offsetTop - elem.parentOffset.offsetTop`. is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

`.position().top` in jQuery is equivalent to `.offsetTop` in javascript.

Both articles referenced in the question are accurate.

Just remember that, as mentioned in the article on `.offsetTop`, if you want the offset relative to the immediate parent element, you must set the `position` attribute on that element.

I am still confused by this naming scheme, and I'm not sure how to get the behavior of jQuery `.offset()` in javascript.