# jQuery offset().top slightly off every other time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the inside of a parent div scroll to the next child div on a set interval. However, the scroll only works half the time and I can't figure out why. It should scroll through all 8 children, but only goes through about half.

In this jsfiddle I made, the offset is just 1px off every other time when it should be ~250px off. In my actual code its 0px off, when it should be ~250px off.

https://jsfiddle.net/rLeLogx0/3/

Here's the JS:

```
//scroll to 2nd one first
var index = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    var parent = $('.parent');
    var children = parent.find('.child');
    var target = children.eq(index);   
    var offset = target.offset().top - $('.parent').offset().top;

    //ISSUE: outputs the "same" value every other time
    console.log(target.offset().top);

    parent.animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 200);
    index = (index+1) % children.length;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for your offset calculation:

```
var offset = target.position().top + parent.scrollTop();
```

Update jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLeLogx0/21/

**UPDATE:**

If you truly want your `offset` variable to contain the offset, you can increment the value within the `scrollTop` parameter in your `.animate()`

```
var target = children.eq(index);

[...]

parent.animate({
    scrollTop: '+='+offset
}, 200);
```

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLeLogx0/23/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var child = $('.parent .child'), index = 0;

  var scrollIt = function() {
    var top = child.eq(index).offset().top;
    
    index++;

    if (index >= child.length) {
      index = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollIt();
    }, 1000);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top });
  }
  
  scrollIt();
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>  
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `position().top` instead of `offset.top()`

see the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)

Comment: I tried replacing offset with position, but it doesn't help. https://jsfiddle.net/rLeLogx0/17/. Perhaps I need to change more though.

Comment: Turns out I had to use position. @Prusprus provided the exact line above with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `offset` is giving you the distance from the top of the parent to the next target, because the child top value is updating all the time, but setting `scrollTop` is an absolute distance, not an offset. Here's the code you should use:

```
//scroll to 2nd one first
var index = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    var parent = $('.parent');
    var children = parent.find('.child');
    var target = children.eq(index);   
    var offset = target.offset().top - $('.parent').offset().top;

    //outputs the same value every other time
    console.log(target.offset().top);

    var newScroll = parent.scrollTop() + offset;

    parent.animate({
        scrollTop: newScroll
    }, 200);
    index = (index+1) % children.length;
}, 1000);
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvs6Ltgu/