# offset().left vs position().left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hope you can clarify something for me please

I was looking into carousels, found an excellent one and replicated in my code

for reference this is the one I looked at, it's really good and easy to understand

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-obligatory-slider/

Anyway, I have implemented that and I thought I'd do my own controllers, so I grabbed a few images and positioned them absolutely inside the container with the pictures (screenshot attached for reference).

[image]

Let's have a look at some code.

This is the HTML structure. the `carouselWrapper` div contains the images and the controllers

```
<body>
<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carouselWrapper">
<ul>
<li><img src="image1.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
<div class="sliderNav">
<button data-dir="prev" class="left transparent"></button>
<button data-dir="next" class="right transparent"></button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- end of carousel -->

</body>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

Nothing too involved, the `carouselWrapper` has default `position:static`.

```
.carouselWrapper{
    width:500px; /*size of the pix*/
    /* height:375px; */
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.carouselWrapper ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width:10000px;  

}
 .sliderNav button.right{
    background:url("controllersRight.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
    width:48px;
    height:39px;
}
.sliderNav button.left{
    background:url(controllersLeft.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    width:48px;
    height:39px;
}
 .sliderNav button.left, .sliderNav button.right{
    position:absolute;
    border:0;
}
```

And here is the relevant part of the script that positions the two controllers.

Again, nothing fancy: I get all the widths and heights I need and then update the top and left value of both the controllers.

```
/*positioning the controllers*/
    var containerWidth = $(".carouselWrapper").width();//get width of
    var containerHeight = $(".carouselWrapper").height();
    var controllerWidth = $(".sliderNav button").width();
    var controllerHeight = $(".sliderNav button").height();
    var $controllerPrev = $("button.left"); 
    var $controllerNext = $("button.right");
    var imageContainerPosLeft = $(".carouselWrapper").offset().left;
    var imageContainerPosTop = $(".carouselWrapper").position().top;
    var controllersTop = (containerHeight / 2) - controllerHeight;
    var controller1Left = imageContainerPosLeft;
    var controller2Left = (imageContainerPosLeft + containerWidth ) - controllerWidth ;
    //set the position of the two controller dynamically
    $controllerPrev.css({
        "top":controllersTop,
        "left":controller1Left      
    });
    $controllerNext.css({
        "top":controllersTop,
        "left":controller2Left
    });

    console.log("width of picture container is " + containerWidth + " controller width " + controllerWidth + " left pos is  "+ imageContainerPosLeft + " top pos is " + imageContainerPosTop + " container height " + containerHeight + " new controller top position: " +  controllersTop + " controller1 left pos is " + controller1Left + "second controller left pos is " + controller2Left + " controller height is " + controllerHeight);
```

I would like to draw your attention to this line:

`var imageContainerPosLeft = $(".carouselWrapper").offset().left;`

Here I am using `offset()` and it works fine in every browser, but my first choice was `position().left` instead.

When I used `position()` I noticed that only Firefox, IE7 and 8 and opera worked ok. Safari, Chrome, IE9 and 10 made a mess, the controllers were shifted to the left of the page.

I run a few console logs and found out that the culprit was actually that `position().left` which was returning a value of 0 and I was expecting something like 710px.

So I replaced it with `offset().left` and now it is all fine in every browser. Now, I looked at the API for both methods and it says that

*The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent.*

Funnily enough the parent of `carouselWrapper` is the body tag which has no explicit position declared.

So my questions are:

**1)Is that the reason why the position method failed?**

**2)If so why did it fail only in certain browsers and not in others? I mean even IE7 and 8 got it right!**

**3)As an alternative, rather than fixing the problem using `offset().left`, would it be fair to say that I could have fixed it by adding `position:relative` to the body tag?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)