# applying .css property on a dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set the css left property value on items. Below is the code:

```
if (priorityObj.UpcomingActivities() != "") {
    $.each(priorityObj.UpcomingActivities(), function (i, v) {
        monthPosition = v.ActivityDateToDisplay().split(',')[0].substring(0, 3).trim();
        if (monthPosition != "") {
            activitymonthpos = $('#servicePlanMonths').find('#sp_month_' + monthPosition).position().left;
            $(curelement).find('.priority-icon').offset({ left: activitymonthpos });
        }
        else {
            monthLeftPosition = $('#servicePlanMonths').find('#sp_month_' + startingMonth).position().left;
            $(curelement).find('.priority-icon').offset({ left: monthLeftPosition });
        }
    });
}
```

The **monthPosition** variable is used fetch the current month and based on this gets the css left property value and then apply that property value. This code is running fine. But the issue that I am facing is with

```
$(curelement).find('.priority-icon').offset({ left: monthLeftPosition });
```

Since this class is binded with the UpcomingActivities() function and this function can have more than two values. So, if I have two values, then it apply the css and set the same left property of [0] index for both the values. I wanted that it should set the left property on only one value and diff left property value on the other.

How can I make it work so that the left property of the css is applied on different items.

I know the problem is with the below statement but I couldn't find out how to resolve it

```
$(curelement).find('.priority-icon').offset({ left: monthLeftPosition });
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: why don't you set the left property with `.css(prp, val)`

Comment: @Jai: by using the said statement, I was facing issue with the positioning. and there is difference between left and offset: for more info on this please go to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset

Comment: Does anyone know the solution of it??

Answer (score 0):

You could set the CSS property left using jQuery

```
$('#yourDiv').css( "left", 200 );
```

Live example here, click the blu div to change is left position:

https://jsbin.com/boqadeweqi/edit?html,output

```js
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).css( "left", 200 );
});
```

```css
div {
    position:absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" style="background-color:blue;">Click me!</div>
```

For more information look at [jQuery API here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: my question is different here... I am successful in applying the css. but when I have two object, the same css is applied to each object.i.e left property is assigned to each object

Comment: @Yash thanks for commenting, could you please create a jsfiddle where you show us exactly your error, so we can try to help you fix it :) Let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.css({"prop":"value","prop":"value"});`

http://api.jquery.com/css/