# Jquery position() method get different value in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, safari, position

I am creating a html project. In this project I want to add animated.css classes some divs when these divs are shown. I get position div with position() method. But there is a problem. In chrome, position() method runs when div comes to the top of the page. In safari, position() method runs when div comes to the bottom of the page.

Here is the codes

```
var posServices = $('.services').position();
var posAbout = $('.about').position();
var posTeam = $('.team').position();
var posPort = $('.portfolio').position();

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > posServices.top) {
    $('.services-column').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
  } 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > posAbout.top) {
    $('.about-slider').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
    $('.about-content').addClass('animated slideInRight');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > posTeam.top){
    $('.team-column').addClass('animated bounceIn');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > posPort.top){
    $('.sub-portfolio').addClass('animated swing');
  }
});
```

To be more descriptive I shared a video on youtube. Please watch and help to solve my problem. [Here is the link](https://youtu.be/z_bALHI8oUI)

Thank you

Comment: try to use .offset()  instead of .position()  ... may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

This really can be the solution, ie. using .offset() instead of .position()
According to [JQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/) .position() gets the position related to the parent offset element, but the .offset() method gets the position related to the document element.
So the solution could be:

`var posServices = $('.services').offset();
var posAbout = $('.about').offset();
var posTeam = $('.team').offset();
var posPort = $('.portfolio').offset(); //ETC.`

Have lots of fun!