# animate ScrollTop in a position: fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't seem to be able to scroll the page when on a div with positon = fixed.

Can someone please help? I'm using the following jquery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".example").offset().top
}, 750);
```

also I had to make it so that the body has a property of overflow: hidden (not scrollable)

My problem: The code above does not work in a div that is position: fixed. I'm trying to scroll to another element inside a div that is position fixed.

```
<div class="overlay"> 
    <div class="example"></div>
</div>

.overlay {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

I can't scroll to the example element inside overlay div because overlay div is position fixed.

When I use the code below:

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".example").offset().top
}, 750);
```

Inside the overlay (class name) div, it doesn't work because the overlay div has a position fixed.

Comment: so how do I scroll to another div inside a div that is position: fixed?

Comment: The question isn't very clear - perhaps some screenshots or a jsFiddle which reproduces your issue would help?

Comment: I am saying that the jquery code doesn't work inside the div with class name "overlay"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is simple. You're calling for scroll on `html, body`, not on your `fixed` element. You'll need to set `overflow` to `auto` and call the scroll animation on your actual element.

Like this:

```js
$(document)
 .on('click', '#btnScr1', function(e) {
  // NOTICE: call on actual fixed element
  $('#example').animate({ scrollTop: $(".exp").offset().top }, 750);
 })
 .on('click', '#btnScr2, #btnScr4', function(e) {
  // NOTICE: call on actual fixed element
  $('#example').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 750);
 })
 .on('click', '#btnScr3', function(e) {
  // NOTICE: call on actual fixed element
  $('#example').animate({ scrollTop: $('#example').prop("scrollHeight") }, 750);
 })
```

```css
#example { bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: auto; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0; }
.exp { text-align: center; }
p b i { background: yellow; color: red; padding: .5em 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">

<h1><center><button id="btnScr1">Click here to make scroll</button></center></h1><ul><li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li><li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li><li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li><li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li></ul><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p><h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1><p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p><dl><dt>Definition list</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd><dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd></dl><h2>Header Level 2</h2><ol><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li></ol><blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote><h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<p class="exp"><button id="btnScr2">Scroll to Top</button><b><i>Scroll to this</i></b><button id="btnScr3">Scroll to Bottom</button></p>

<ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li></ul><pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
display: block; 
width: 300px; 
height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre><dl><dt>Definition list</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd><dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.</dd></dl><ul><li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li><li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li><li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li><li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li></ul><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p><h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1><p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p><dl><dt>Definition list</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd><dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dt><dd>Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</dd></dl><h2>Header Level 2</h2><ol><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li><li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li></ol><blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote><h3>Header Level 3</h3>
  
  <h1><center><button id="btnScr4">Scroll to Top</button></center></h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this fixes the issue, but now $('#example').animate({ scrollTop: $(".exp").offset().top }, 750); doesn't always scroll to the right location. It scrolls to the right location sometimes

Comment: @BrownPO You'll have to post an example of your page and code. Sounds like you have some other interference or don't quite understand what all is going on here. Ask any question you like, i'll help what I can, but it would be really helpful if you could post the page you're having trouble with as a [`code snippet`](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: turns out the problem was using offset instead of position()

Comment: @BrownPO yeah, that would have to do with your layout. Your document (`html|body`) probably has no height or an altered (`margin`) offset. Check out this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset/#answer-3202038) for more info.