# Scroll to navigation only working from first element

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, navigation

I am a beginner in javascript and can't quite grasp what I need to change to make this work.

This is the [link](http://daynacasey.com/brewingthesublime/).

I have a container with a collapsable fixed navigation. You should be able to click on each of the nav items and scroll to the chapter. The thing is: it only works coming from the top or 'Chapter 1'.
When I click on a nav chapter twice it goes up and down and doesn't just simply go to its anchor.

This is the javascript that I found when I had it set up without a fixed navigation — what to change for it to work the way I want?:

```
function scrollNav() {
  $('.nav a').click(function(){
    //Toggle Class
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
    var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.'+theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');
    //Animate
    $('#container').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(   $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 180
    }, 400);
    return false;
  });
  $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
}
scrollNav();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you give us a https://jsfiddle.net/ that shows the same behavior?

Comment: I don't think `$( $(this).attr('href')).offset().top` does what you think it does, but it's hard to say without being able to easily inspect js & html

Comment: Hi Ebbishop, thanks for replying.
It's my first time setting up a jsfiddle: here's the link. https://jsfiddle.net/fhyjgop7/
I can't get the javascript to work though. I read some stackoverflow threads to see how to solve (change js menu to No wrap-in<head>) but no luck yet. 
I've added the sticky titles also, for the complete feeling of this container. Could also have something to do with the problem. Thankyou

Comment: is the answer below helpful? does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! It's perfect.

Comment: in that case, please as answered! :)

Comment: that is, please *mark as answered.

Comment: I think I am too much of a newbie – If I have less than a reputation of 15, the checkmark is recorded but not displayed publicly.... It says.

But I consider this answered.

Answer (score 0):

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/k86dr5dy/3/).  I added jquery library, and a console for debugging.

There were two main problems I spotted:

First, use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` here. Offset is always relative to the document, while position is relative to the offset parent (which may or may not be the document). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202038/5799673).  Since you're interested in the position relative to the parent container, it's `.position().top` that you should use.

Once that's in place, it's easier to reason about the correct value of scrollTop. When you've scrolled past the target element, its position relative to the `#container` will be negative. If the `chapterPosition` is `-300` and the current scrollTop is `1000`, we want to scroll to 700.

Note, however, that this is because the `#container` div is fixed-position.  In the fiddle above, I put in an alternate way to calculate scroll, if you didn't want sticky headers & so didn't need `#container` to be fixed.