# Get position for alert box in scrollable div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

How do I adjust the position of the alert box on click in a scrollable `div` with ng-repeat? As my `div` height is small and if I give `position: absolute` alert box is getting hidden for the first row. `z-index` is not working. And if I give it `position: fixed` then that box is moving down as I scroll. I want to keep that box displayed on the clicked-on button like a tooltip.

Comment: Can you add code, or context.. Something to work on it

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Modal dialogs can **double error rates,** increase time to task completion, and are near-universally despised by users. Alternate means of notification are often available and should be utilized wherever possible and appropriate. See [What research is there suggesting modal dialogs are disruptive?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-research-is-there-suggesting-modal-dialogs-are-disruptive).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it seems that you would like the position of the clicked element. Seeing as how you are using jquery, you could do that with something like this

```
$('#button-clicked').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).position().left;
    var y = $(this).position().top;
    //position alert box using positions from clicked button
})
```

check out [jQuery: Difference between position() and offset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset) for more information