# why is $(...).position().top returning 0?

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following code:

```
<div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: black"></div>

<table id="pets" class="table-border" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 1em; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Breed</td>
        <td class="highlightTop">Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="petName" style="width: 100%"/></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="highlight"><input type="numbers" name="age" style="width: 100%"/></td>
</table>
```

When I do `$('#pets .highlightTop').position().top` I get 0 back. Why? The fact that there's a 50px tall div above the table should mean that it's at least 50, should it not?

Since it isn't 50, how can I get the actual position of the element?

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/c1qj09sn/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/position/ <= position() is based upon the elements relationship to it's parent element

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/position/): _“Description: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, **relative to the offset parent**. […] Contrast this with [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), which retrieves the current position **relative to the document**.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`position`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) returns the position of the element relative to it's parent.

So relative to `#pets`. Which is 0

What you are looking for is [`offset`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)

the value of the offset will be in this case

`50`(height of the only element between your element and top of the document div) + `16px` ( =1em margin-top of parent ) + `8px` (body margin) = `72px`

```js
console.log($('#pets .highlightTop').offset().top);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background: black"></div>

<table id="pets" class="table-border" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 1em; border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Breed</td>
        <td class="highlightTop">Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="petName" style="width: 100%"/></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="highlight"><input type="numbers" name="age" style="width: 100%"/></td>
</table>
```

Read more here -> [jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202008/jquery-difference-between-position-and-offset)